# What happens to blocked light in a color filter?

Tags: optics, visible-light

What happens to the light when it passes a colour filter? How does the electro magnetic radiation that doesnot pass through get lost as heat? What is the internal process that actually happens?

Comment: It does get lost in heat.  You can actually burn the filter if you input too much power in it.

Comment: Then what happens when light gets reflected off everyday objects that are coloured? Shouldn't the same happen there too, only because of which we see everyday objects in different colours?
And also, what actually happens chemically in any object that displays colour?